# How come this use of stringstream doesn't work on linux, but works on Mac?

Tags: c++

I have this code to convert some `t` to an integer:

```
template <class T>
int toInt(const T& t)
{
  int i = -1;
  (std::stringstream() << t) >> i;

   return i;
}
```

This works fine on my Mac, but whenever I try to use it on the linux machines at my school, it fails to compile. I have to switch to something like this:

```
template <class T>
int toInt(const T& t)
{
  int i = -1;
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << t;
  ss >> i;

  return i;
}
```

Which works fine.

Why is this?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: In addition, please identify the actual compilers you're using.  "Mac" and "linux" are not compiler brands.  Is it g++?  clang? What version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator `<<` inherited by `std::basic_stringstream` from `std::basic_ostream` returns a `std::basic_ostream &` reference as result. Operator `>>` is not aplicable to a `std::basic_ostream`. For this reason the expression

```
(std::stringstream() << t) >> i
```

is not supposed to compile.

It is not immediately clear to me why it compiles on your Mac.

---

As an additional note, in pre-C++11 version of the language the

```
std::stringstream() << t
```

would already be ill-formed for those `t` that rely on non-member implementation of `operator <<`. Freestanding implementations of `operator <<` take a non-const reference as their LHS parameter.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo: No. A *refernce* is returned. Returning a reference does not result in slicing. The reference is still bound to [the subobject of] the original object.